# ADD/Remove button for dropdown fields in gravity forms

Tags: dropdown, gravity-forms-plugin, gravityforms

Is there any way to add/remove additional rows option to **dropdown fields **?

[image: need something like this]

same as the `+` button in list fields

Comment: I need + button for dropdown fields & NOT dropdown for list fields

Comment: Don't put question details in comments. Be clear about what you want, and what you have tried. Show some code. Also: questions should be stand alone. Few people are going to visit your external link.